# Why new while returning for overloaded operators for DBBool (TriState) implementation in C#

Tags: c#, tri-state-logic

If you look for the [`DBBool` implementation in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6292hy1k.aspx), few overloaded operators (logical operators `|`, `&`, `!`) new while returning. I believe that is not necessary and a small waste of memory. DBBool is a struct and a copy is made when it's passed into a method so there is no reason for that.

```
// Logical negation operator. Returns True if the operand is False, Null 
// if the operand is Null, or False if the operand is True. 
public static DBBool operator !(DBBool x)
{
    return new DBBool(-x.value);
}
// Logical AND operator. Returns False if either operand is False, 
// Null if either operand is Null, otherwise True. 
public static DBBool operator &(DBBool x, DBBool y)
{
    return new DBBool(x.value < y.value ? x.value : y.value);
}
// Logical OR operator. Returns True if either operand is True,  
// Null if either operand is Null, otherwise False. 
public static DBBool operator |(DBBool x, DBBool y)
{
    return new DBBool(x.value > y.value ? x.value : y.value);
}
```

It should be this way without newing.

```
public static DBBool operator !(DBBool x)
{
    if (x.value > 0) return False;
    if (x.value < 0) return True;
    return Null;
}
public static DBBool operator &(DBBool x, DBBool y)
{
    return x.value < y.value ? x : y;
}
public static DBBool operator |(DBBool x, DBBool y)
{
    return x.value > y.value ? x : y;
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe any memory is wasted?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I see, new will initialize a 'DBBool' value on stack and the memory with be reclaimed when the method exits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. it is a struct, so "new" really means "initialize a value on the stack" - this is cheap and is not the same as a new object
2. most structs are immutable; I'm guessing this is too; hence it can't just mutate the parameter value and return that - it must initialize a new value with the desired contents

Comment: 1. agree. 2. structs are immutable, agreed but i don't agree with the rest. ex: i can mutate a string parameter and return it. i've tried the changed code and it works correctly.

Comment: @hIpPy: You can't mutate a string, and strings aren't structs anyway. It's not clear what you mean, really.

Comment: @hlpPy *reassigning* a parameter is not the same as *mutating* the value of the parameter. And no, you can't mutate a string. And technically, it is wrong to say "structs are immutable": they almost always *should* be, but some (few) are mutable - this usually leads to crazy amounts of confusion.

Comment: i meant to say i can change a string param in a method and return it and strings are immutable. there is nothing preventing me from doing that.

Comment: @hlpPy right; but that is unrelated to the question. In that scenario, the value for the new string needs to come from somewhere; that is what the "new" is doing: giving it a value

Comment: @MarcGravell, regarding #1, technically the allocation of memory on heap and stack is the same but the deallocation on stack is cheaper. :) (quoting Eric Lippert).